# Jhipster 4 angular 4 + spring boot + mysql (Register accessdenied)

Tags: jhipster

I'm testing the tool Jhipser 4 and I generated an app with JWT token and social media login(facebook) + Mysql database for prod and development.
When I launched the application I have the home page but when I click on "Register a new account" I am redirected to the accessdenied page and the sign in pop appears.

I have also try to login with facebook, the user is added to the database with the role user but I'm also redirected to the /accessdenied page after the facebook sign in.

I have no error on server side but I can see that I'm not authentified on the client side...

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an open issue for it already. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5542

Comment: In deed did not see it. Thanks !